# cognos 10.2.2 workspace auto submit

Tags: cognos

I have created a workspace dashboard, and the reprompt value on the widgets keeps defaulting to the last value the workspace was run on.  Is there a way to keep that from autosubmitting on the last value or defaulting to null?

Answer (score 0):

We setup a saved read-only version of the dashboard for users to view.  It had all the preferred defaults saved.  If users wanted to make changes they had to save a copy in their own space, so their prompt changes would only affect their personal copy.